# Node.js array empty in import() file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typescript

I am trying to build an array path where when I call `Router.group`, the first parameter is pushed onto the end of the `this.groupPath` array, and this works. However, when I dump the data of the array within an `import()` the array is empty. What is causing this?

```
export class Router {
  // The current path
  private static groupPath: string[] = []

  // A grouping of routes
  public static group(path: string, callback: Function) {
    this.groupPath.push(path)
    callback()
    this.groupPath.pop()
  }

  // Add a post route
  public static post(routePath: string, callback: string | ((client: Client, mongo: Mongo) => void | Response)) {
    let r = new route(path.join(...this.groupPath, routePath), 'post', callback)
    this.routes.push(r)
    return r
  }
}
```

I am then trying to call group like this, and my `Router.groupPath` outputs the correct array:

```
import { Router } from '../util';

Router.group('/api', () => {
  console.log('before', Router['groupPath']) // outputs: ['/api']
  import('./api')
  console.log('after', Router['groupPath']) // outputs: ['/api']
})
```

However, within the file `./api`, I have this where they array is now empty:

```
import { Router } from '../util'

console.log('in', Router['groupPath']) // outputs: []
Router.post('/install', 'install@install')
Router.post('/install/testMongoConnection', 'install@testConnection')
```

Why is this static property empty?

**Edit:**

I noticed that the outputs are out of order:

```
before [ '/api' ]
after [ '/api' ]
in []
```

Which to me indicates that the import isn't running synchronously. I was expecting this to be the output:

```
before [ '/api' ]
in ['/api']
after [ '/api' ]
```

Comment: The `Router` you import in `./api` is a different instance. Have you tried passing `Router` in?

Comment: It should be a cached instance of the Router....

Comment: Why are you using dynamic import in the first place? It isn't desirable in such cases exactly because of the way it works.

Comment: @estus What else would I use?

Comment: Regular imports for static imports like `./api`. `require` for dynamic imports, since TS type safety isn't reachable for the latter any way.

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like that `import()` returns a promise. To solve the issue, I need to do 2 things:

1. In the group callback prefix `async` to the function

   1. `await` the `import` to look like `await import('./api')`
2. In `Router.group` make it `async` as well

   1. `await` the `callback()` to look like `await callback()`

So now the callback looks like this:

```
Router.group('/api', async () => {
  await import('./api')
})
```

The group method now looks like this:

```
public static async group(path: string, callback: Function) {
  this.groupPath.push(path)
  await callback()
  this.groupPath.pop()
}
```